# Confusion about Post-Newtonian orbital motion (Damour-Deruelle)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, binary-stars, post-newtonian

In their famous paper in 1985 ([link](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=AIHPA_1985__43_1_107_0)), Damour&Deruelle describe the orbital motion for a binary system taking into account first-order post-Newtonian corrections (1PN). The solution is given in their eqs. (7.1-7.2), according to which the binary separation $a_R$ (just to make an example) is:

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
a_R= - \dfrac{GM}{2E}\left[ 1- \dfrac{1}{2}(\nu-7)\dfrac{E}{c^2} \right]
\end{equation}

where $\nu \doteq (m_1 m_2) / (m_1+m_2)^2$. However, in their Appendix B, the authors show the equation of motion by using the Lagrange's method of variation of constants. In this case, all the orbital parameters are functions of time: for example, the binary separation is now (see Eqs. B11):

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
a(t)= \bar{a}\left[ 1+ \dfrac{GM}{c^2 p (1-e^2)}*f(e,\phi) \right]
\end{equation}

where $\bar{a}$ is a constant of integration, $e$ is the eccentricity (Keplerian or PN?), $p=a(1-e^2)$, $\phi$ is the true anomaly, and $f$ is a given function of $e$ and $\phi$ that I omitted for brevity.

My question is:

(a) Which is the physical difference between $a_R$ and $a(t)$?

(b) I know that relativistic corrections make the orbital parameters time-dependent; so why (1) does not depend on time while (2) does?

(c) If a want to simulate the orbital motion at 1PN for 10 years, which set of eqs. should I use?